# Python Multiprocessing disallows printing in main process after processes are created

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I was trying to make sure I had this code setup properly before starting the processes. After adding some print statements I found that only 'outer' and 'inner' are printing and I can not understand why the other print statements are not executing.

```py
import multiprocessing
from itertools import product

retailer_ids = [41, 499]  # defined retailers
product_ids = [4, 5, 10, 11, 12]  # ProductIDs to search on
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSES = 2

retailer_products = list(product(retailer_ids, product_ids))

# Start processing the retailer/product combinations
for i in range(0, len(retailer_products), NUMBER_OF_PROCESSES):
    print('outer')
    try:
        current_processes = []
        for j in range(0, NUMBER_OF_PROCESSES):
            print('inner')
            process = multiprocessing.Process(scrape_retailer_product, retailer_products[i+j])
            #process.start()
            current_processes.append(process)
        # wait for current process to finish before starting more
        print('waiting for processes to complete')
        for p in current_processes:
            p.join()

        print('completed')

    # something bad happened during process creation or a
    # a scrape process returned with an exception it could not handle
    except Exception as e:
        for p in current_processes:
            p.terminate()
            print('term')
            exit()
```

Comment: If you replace `scrape_retailer_product` with a noop do you still see this behavior?

Comment: what did you mean by noop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your are catching all exceptions. So your code was not passing the correct arguments to the `Process` constructor (which generated an `AssertionError`), but your `catch` statement was silently handling the exception.

The current exception is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MiguelAngel\Downloads\test.py", line 19, in <module>
    process = multiprocessing.Process(scrape_retailer_product, args=(retailer_products[i+j]))
  File "C:\Users\MiguelAngel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 82, in __init__
    assert group is None, 'group argument must be None for now'
AssertionError: group argument must be None for now
```

I suppose that `scrape_retailer_product` is the function that should be executed in the new process. Therefore, according to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process), the call to the constructor should be:

```py
process = multiprocessing.Process(target=scrape_retailer_product, 
                                  args=(retailer_products[i+j],))
```

If you want to catch all multiprocessing exceptions, you should catch `multiprocessing.ProcessError`. According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.ProcessError), it is the base class of all multiprocessing exceptions.

Comment: I have an exit in my exception handling so it would have only printed 'outer' once if  it was hitting down there. But adding the argument names target and args did help out.

Comment: @KevinSmeeks Well, not really. The `current_processes` list was never filled, as the exception was being raised before the `current_processes.append(process)` statement. So, the execution thread would not get inside the `for` loop in the `except` block, and thus the `exit()` would not we executed.